# Spring Websockets based on XML and based on Annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to write own chat on websocket + spring security + springBoot. Now I have in my project:

**Security-context.xml:**

```
    ...
            <intercept-url pattern="/login/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
            <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
            <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
            <form-login/>
        </http>

        <authentication-manager>
            <authentication-provider>
                <user-service>
                    <user name="bob" password="test" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
                    <user name="jim" password="test" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
                    <user name="a" password="1" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
...
```

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="wsproblem" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app">
        <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/ws">
            <websocket:sockjs />
        </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
        <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic, /user" />
    </websocket:message-broker>
```

, I have standart **web.xml** and **root-context.xml**.

Also I have a simple **controller**:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }

    @MessageMapping("/greeting")
    public void greeting(Principal principal) {
        String reply = "hello " + principal.getName();
        System.out.println("sending " + reply);
        simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(principal.getName(), "/reply", reply);
    }
```

And **my question** is:

How to rewrite this code (eg how to migrate)  from xml to annotated java class files like *WebSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer*

Answer (score 0):

You can very well do something like this

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketConfig.class);

    public WebSocketConfig(){
        logger.info("---WebSocket---");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/temp-ws").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/temp-web");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/queue");   // Enables a simple in-memory broker

        // rabbitmq broker
//        registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic", "/queue")
//                .setRelayHost("localhost")
//                .setRelayPort(61613)
//                .setClientLogin("guest")
//                .setClientPasscode("guest");

    }


}
```

Comment: Thanx a lot! Thats what i've looking for. So, after your edits, I can delete web.xml, root-context, securirity-context, servlet-context, isn't it? Or I should move code from these xml to another annotated configuration java clases?

Comment: Your question was for web socket part so remove only web socket part of code  from xml

Answer (score 0):

You can find the running project on github.
https://github.com/tanoliusman/UrlShortener

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").withSockJS();
}

@Override
public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void addReturnValueHandlers(List<HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void configureClientOutboundChannel(ChannelRegistration arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean configureMessageConverters(List<MessageConverter> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

```
function connect() {
        var socket = new SockJS('/gs-guide-websocket');
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
            console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
            stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function (greeting) {
                showGreeting(greeting.body);
            });
        });
    }
    function disconnect() {
        if (stompClient !== null) {
            stompClient.disconnect();
        }
        setConnected(false);
        console.log("Disconnected");
    }
    function sendName() {
        stompClient.send("/app/hello", {}, JSON.stringify({'name': $("#name").val()}));
    }
    function showGreeting(message) {
        var object = jQuery.parseJSON( message).name;
        if(object == url){
            value = 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very clarifying information! But.... Your example has only websocket realization part. Without SpringSecurity. But in my code I have Spring Security authorization (but just, its a pittty, in xml). So, how I can add SpringSecurity functionality in your code... May be you saw some examples on the Web... )